# Impala - Get for all tables in database concentenated columns

Tags: impala

Lets say I have a database A with tables B1 and B2.
B1 has columns C1 and C2

and B2 has columns D1, D2 and D3.

I am looking for an Impala query that yields the following desired output:

```
B1    | "C1+C2"

B2    | "D1+D2+D3"
```

where "D1+D2+D3" and "C1+C2" are concatenated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the concatenated columns in a new table? Or do you want to add the concatenated columns to your existing tables? Either way, you can use the code below in impala to concatenated columns:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(C1,C2) AS concat_fields
, "B1" AS table_name
FROM B1
UNION
SELECT 
CONCAT(D1,D2,D3) AS concat_fields
, "B2" AS table_name
FROM B2
```

Comment: thanks a lot as it does answer my question perfectly. It turns out i was a bit unprecise in my questions. As the title indicated i would like to have the Output for all tables, which could also be up to 300. Therefore, I made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338631/impala-get-for-multiple-tables-in-database-concentenated-columns. If you find the time to also take a look there, it would be very much  appreciated! Thanks again!